MySQL - SLAVE does not receive updates from "secondary" master?
I have the following setup

If I write something in MASTER A, the slave receive the update, but if I write something in master B, the slave does not receive the update. Is this right? Is there a way to propague the updates in master B to slave?

It should work if each instance has a distinct server_id and MASTER A has enabledlog_slave_updates (now called log_replica_updates in MySQL 8 or later).

Thank you, it worked by enabling log_slave_updates on master A!! Can I leave this parameter enabled on master B as well?

Yes, it's safe to leave that option enabled on both instances. Binary log events are annotated with the server-id, and an instance ignores events that are noted with its own server-id. So you won't cause an infinite loop if you arrange reciprocal replication like this.

Thank you for your help!

Just so it's clear : 1) do you have circular replication working ??? In other words, is MasterA a Slave to MasterB and is MasterB a Slave to MasterA ??? 2) Do you write things on MasterA and expect it to be on MasterB ???

Yes, is a master-master, but we only write in master A. We have a master-master only to simplify a switchover, the application only need to point to master B if necessary. The  master-master works fine, my only doubt was about write on master B and replicate it to the slave of the master A.

I managed many replica-sets with this topology at my last job. It works fine. It's convenient because you can do switchover without reconfiguring much.  But both A and B need to have log_slave_updates enabled. It's also super helpful if you use GTID auto-positioning in the replication configuration. That way you can switch C to a new source without worrying about binary log coordinates.
